# SwiftUI ObservableObject not refreshing data on views

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

I'm trying to use SwiftUI's `ObservableObject`, but I can't seem to update my view's properties.

This is my `ContentView.swift`

```
import SwiftUI


final class JiraData: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        // TODO use real service
        self.worklog = self.jiraService.getCounter(tickets: 2, minutes: 120, status: "BELOW")
    }
    
    init(hours: Double, tickets: Int, status: Status) {
        self.worklog = Worklog(minutesLogged: Int(hours) * 60, totalTickets: tickets, status: status)
    }
    
    /// Refreshes the data in this object, by calling the underlying service again
    ///
    /// Despite SwiftUI's Observable pattern, I need the UI to toggle this interaction
    func refresh() {
        self.worklog = self.jiraService.getCounter(tickets: Int.random(in: 3..<5), minutes: 390, status: "OK")
        print("Now mocked is: \(self.worklog)")
    }
    
    func getTimeAndTickets() -> String {
        return "You logged \(String(format: "%.2f", Double(self.worklog.minutesLogged) / 60.0)) hours in \(self.worklog.totalTickets) tickets today"
    }
    
    func getStatus() -> String {
        // TODO removed hardcoded part
        return "You are on \"\(Status.below.rawValue)\" status"
    }
    
    var jiraService = MockedService()
    @Published var worklog: Worklog
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var jiraData = JiraData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(jiraData.getTimeAndTickets())
                .font(Font.system(size: 20.0))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16.0)
                .frame(width: 360.0, height: 80.0, alignment: .topLeading)
            Text(jiraData.getStatus())
                .font(Font.system(size: 20.0))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16.0)
                .frame(width: 360.0, height: 80, alignment: .topLeading)
            Button(action: {
                jiraData.refresh()  // TODO unneeded?
            })
            {
                Text("Refresh")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            Button(action: {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
            })
            {
                Text("Quit")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 16.0)
            .frame(width: 360.0, alignment: .trailing)
        }
        .padding(0)
        .frame(width: 360.0, height: 360.0, alignment: .top)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(jiraData: JiraData(hours: 6.5, tickets: 2, status: Status.below))
    }
}
#endif
```

The data structures are:

```
import Foundation


/// This is a Worklog possible status
enum Status: String, Codable, Equatable {
    case below = "below"
    case ok = "ok"
    case overtime = "overtime"
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // If decoding fails, we default to "below"
        guard let rawValue = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) else {
            self = .below
            return
        }
        self = Status(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .below
    }
}

/// This represents a Worklog on JIRA
struct Worklog: Codable {
    var minutesLogged: Int
    var totalTickets: Int
    var status: Status
}

/// Parses a JSON obtained from the JAR's stdout
func parse(json: String) -> Worklog {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    let data = Data(json.utf8)
    if let jsonWorklogs = try? decoder.decode(Worklog.self, from: data) {
        return jsonWorklogs
    }
    // TODO maybe handle error differently
    return Worklog(minutesLogged: 0, totalTickets: 0, status: Status.below)
}
```

My Service is just a mock:

```
import Foundation


struct MockedService {
    func getCounter(tickets: Int, minutes: Int, status: String) -> Worklog {
        let json = "{\"totalTickets\":\(tickets),\"minutesLogged\":\(minutes),\"status\":\"\(status)\"}"
        print("At MockedService: \(json)")
        return parse(json: json)
    }
}
```

On startup, I'm getting this printed on the console

```
At MockedService: {"totalTickets":2,"minutesLogged":120,"status":"BELOW"}
2020-11-09 20:47:17.163710-0300 JiraWorkflows[2171:14431] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

At this point, my app looks like this (which is correct).

[image]

I know, the UI looks awful so far :(

But then, after I click on `Refresh`, the UI isn't updated, despite seeing this on the console

```
2020-11-09 20:47:17.163710-0300 JiraWorkflows[2171:14431] Metal API Validation Enabled
At MockedService: {"totalTickets":4,"minutesLogged":390,"status":"OK"}
Now mocked is: Worklog(minutesLogged: 390, totalTickets: 4, status: JiraWorkflows.Status.below)
```

Any ideas on what could be going on here?
Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT after @Asperi 's answer, my `refresh()` function looks like this

```
func refresh() {
        self.worklog = self.jiraService.getCounter(tickets: Int.random(in: 3..<5), minutes: 390, status: "OK")
        print("Now mocked is: \(self.worklog)")
        self.timeAndTicketsMsg = "You logged \(String(format: "%.2f", Double(self.worklog.minutesLogged) / 60.0)) hours in \(self.worklog.totalTickets) tickets today"
        print(self.timeAndTicketsMsg)
        self.statusMsg = "You are on \"\(self.worklog.status.rawValue)\" status"
        print(statusMsg)
    }
```

Which prints:

```
At MockedService: {"totalTickets":4,"minutesLogged":390,"status":"OK"}
Now mocked is: Worklog(minutesLogged: 390, totalTickets: 4, status: JiraWorkflows.Status.below)
You logged 6.50 hours in 4 tickets today
You are on "below" status
```

Which is correct. However, the UI isn't refreshed. I've also changed my `ObservableObject`, which now looks like this:

```
final class JiraData: ObservableObject {
    // rest of the class
    var jiraService = MockedService()
    var worklog: Worklog
    @Published var timeAndTicketsMsg: String
    @Published var statusMsg: String
}
```

and now, my `ContentView` looks like this:

```
@ObservedObject var jiraData = JiraData()
    
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text(jiraData.timeAndTicketsMsg)

    // rest of the Text
    Text(jiraData.statusMsg)
    // rest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in calling functions, like

```
   Text(jiraData.getTimeAndTickets())
```

The refresh happens when there is *dependency between changed property and view body*. Function cannot be tracked for changes.

So you need to refactor your code to the kind

```
   Text(jiraData.timeAndTickets)
```

where `timeAndTickets` is

```
@Published var timeAndTickets: String
```

and you modify it directly whenever `refresh` performed.... and then view will be updated correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question with the new status of the code. Unfortunately, it looks as if something is still missing